# How to use "select new Dto(...)..." construction with @OneToMany relationship in Spring Data JPA @Query?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I need to use "`select new ...`" to construct DTO object in my repository.

I have following classes:

Entity class `Victim`:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "victims")
@Getter
@Setter
@ToString
@Builder
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
public class Victim extends User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
  private Long id;

  @Column(nullable = false, length = 13)
  private String phoneNumber;

  @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
  @Column(nullable = false)
  private UserStatus userStatus = UserStatus.ACTIVE;

  @JsonManagedReference
  @Setter(AccessLevel.PRIVATE)
  @BatchSize(size = 100)
  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "victim", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  @Exclude
  private List<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();

  @JsonManagedReference
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "victim", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private LegalEntityVictim legalEntityVictim;

  @JsonManagedReference
  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "victim", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
  private NaturalPersonVictim naturalPersonVictim;

}
```

Also assume, that Request is the object, which has its own relationship with another object and contains it as well - probably that is the problem, because without using that field in DTO everything works - so the possible question is: “How to construct DTO with inner one-to-many dependency (which could have its own dependencies as well)?”

DTO class `VictimDTO`:

```
@Data
@Builder
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class VictimDto {

  private Long id;

  private String email;

  private String password;

  private String name;

  private String surname;

  private String nameOfOrganization;

  private String phoneNumber;

  private UserStatus userStatus;

  private Collection<Request> requests = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

Repository `VictimRepository`:

```
public interface VictimRepository extends JpaRepository<Victim, Long> {

  @Query("select new com.pavliuk.dto.VictimDto(v.id, v.email, v.password, v.naturalPersonVictim.name, v.naturalPersonVictim.surname, v.legalEntityVictim.nameOfOrganization, v.phoneNumber, v.userStatus, v.requests) from Victim v ")
  Page<VictimDto> findAllDto(Pageable pageable);

}
```

The following hierarchy of SQL tables are defined:
[image: Diagram of SQL table relationship]

And as result I got following logs (I have turned on show-sql ability, so you can inspect also generated query):

```
Hibernate: select victim0_.id as col_0_0_, victim0_.email as col_1_0_, victim0_.password as col_2_0_, naturalper1_.name as col_3_0_, naturalper1_.surname as col_4_0_, legalentit3_.name_of_organization as col_5_0_, victim0_.phone_number as col_6_0_, victim0_.user_status as col_7_0_, . as col_8_0_ from victims victim0_ cross join natural_person_victims naturalper1_ cross join legal_entity_victims legalentit3_ inner join requests requests4_ on victim0_.id=requests4_.victim_id where victim0_.id=naturalper1_.victim_id and victim0_.id=legalentit3_.victim_id limit ?
2023-01-04 08:54:22.282  WARN 37428 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42601
2023-01-04 08:54:22.282 ERROR 37428 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ERROR: syntax error at or near "."
  Position: 273
2023-01-04 08:54:22.293 ERROR 37428 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.p.controller.ErrorHandlingController   : handleException: message: could not extract ResultSet; SQL [n/a]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not extract ResultSet, method: getAll
```

Comment: Since requests is not sortable (because it is a list), maybe exclude it from the dto during the query and then fetch and set requests for each victimDTO that is in the Page by victim id would be a better solution?

findByVictimIdIn(List<Long> victimIds) in request repository to get all the requests related to the page and distrubute them to each DTO in java

Comment: @Curry, yes, your workaround sounds great and accomplish the goal! Thank you

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible because DTO projections in JPQL are inherently scalar. I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Victim.class)
public interface VictimDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getId();
    String getEmail();
    String getPassword();
    String getName();
    String getSurname();
    String getNameOfOrganization();
    String getPhoneNumber();
    UserStatus getUserStatus();
    Collection<RequestDto> getRequests();

    @EntityView(Request.class)
    interface RequestDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`VictimDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, VictimDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<VictimDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!